# Expanding and Shrinking div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need this div to enlarge when hovered and shrink back to default when the mouse is away from the div.

I did this:

```
$('.box').live('hover', function()
{
    if($(this).height() == 145 && $(this).width() == 100)
    {
        $(this).animate({ height: '+=30px', width: '+=30px' }, 500)
        $('.image img').animate({ height: '+=30px', width: '+=30px' }, 500);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).animate({ height: '-=30px', width: '-=30px' }, 500)
        $(this).next().find('.image img').animate({ height: '-=30px', width: '-=30px' }, 500);
    }
});
```

Although, if I keep hovering and moving the mouse away rapidly, it keeps shrinking back down.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/avXJV/1/

I need it to stay intact when hovering and mouse out'ing so that none of the elements shrink to a tiny dot or go very large...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.purexnaturalelements.ca/) is what you're looking for. The key is to use .stop() before running the next step of the animation so it doesn't fire repeatedly.

Comment: Link no longer works. In fact, it doesn't look like this link ever worked; the URL looks like spam for some water filter product or something.

Comment: It *was* an interactive advertisement built by a co-worker. I guess it is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use fixed pixel sizes and not +=, -=..  the hover event is being triggered multiple times and those values are additive.

Every additional time you hover over it, the size is never original and the else clause runs.